# Seeing mobile version of profile page even on desktop

Tags: support

Since a week or two ago I am seeing a mobile version of the profile page served even though I am on Desktop. It's not very usable (waste too much space and harder to navigate) so I want to switch back to the Desktop version, but I can't find any of those 'request desktop site' links looking in the menus..

How do you switch back to Desktop profile ?? Thanks for your help

Comment: It's the new responsivity page. It successfully unifies the experience of the website on all devices. It's vertical view for all screens.

Comment: This still captures everything wrong with the new profile page in a single paragraph. It does feel like an out of place mobile version